# Is it true that the minimum of a quadratic function $f(t) = \lVert X - tY \rVert^2$ yields the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

What motivated me to ask this is a proof I read on the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that finds the minimum of a function $f(t) = \lVert  X - tY \rVert ^2$. The derivative is taken and set to $0$ and as it turns out the projection of vector $X$ on $Y$ is exactly that minimum point and after some lengthy algebra we come up with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  I actually got this from lecture # 4 from Shifrin's Multivariable Calculus lectures on youtube. He makes it a point that he is not using any geometry but simple algebra to show the truth of the theorem and I am Ok with it...it's just that my intuition keeps asking "where did he come up with this function"  but if I tell myself "well if the minimum exists and is substituted back into the original equation it seems to yield the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. If my question is true then I will have to accept the facts of the algebra despite the lack of my intuition of how he came up with the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function $P$ defined as $P(t)=\|X-tY\|^2$ is a polynomial which degree is $2$. In fact, one has $$\forall \ t \ ,\ P(t)=\|Y\|^2t^2-2\langle X|Y \rangle t+\|X\|^2$$
Of which discriminant is $\ \Delta = 4\langle X|Y\rangle^2 -4\|Y\|^2\|X\|^2$. Thus, because $P$ is a positive function, $\Delta <0$ and the CS inequality holds.

Comment: sorry @avs I was still typing when you posted your answer

Comment: if the discriminant is negative then it has a non real root.  Also I don't understand how you got the discriminant nor what this has to do with CS inequality.     Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: I think I have it ...!  the trick is that for any n dimensional vectors X, Y there exist a t that will minimize the function and when this happens Cauchy Schwarz hold true....very slick.   thank you all

Comment: Not exactly : first you pick two vectors $X$ and $Y$ of an n-dimensional euclidian space and the you define the polynomial $P$ of which discriminant, which depends only on $X$ and $Y$, is negative because P is a positive function as the square of the norme of the vector $X-tY$
It is only a discussion on the number of roots of a second degree equation, of which unknown is t. and coeeficients are $\|Y\|^2$, $-2\langle X|Y\rangle$ and $\|X\|^2$

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing.  For any vectors you choose to pick we can find  a t that will prove the inequality without exception.

Comment: It is not about finding one $t$ such that the inequality works... the logical scheme of the prof is "let X and Y be two vectors... [calculus]... the inequality stands" there is no $t $ depending on X and Y because the one thing that gives us the inequality is the discriminant which is an object linked to the function $P $ itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be vectors in the inner product space, and $t$ a real parameter.  Introduce the function
$$
f(t) = (X - tY, X - tY) = ||X - tY||^2.
$$
By construction, this function is nonnegative.  It is also a quadratic polynomial in $t$.  Since $f(t)$ is nonnegative, the quadratic polynomial cannot have two distinct real roots.  Therefore, its discriminant must be nonpositive:
$$
4(X, Y)^2 \leq 4 ||X||^2 ||Y||^2.
$$